# CKEditor 4 custom build based on toolbar config

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I used the [CKEditor Toolbar Configurator](https://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/toolbarconfigurator/index.html#basic) to customize the toolbar. I want to use the [Builder](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/builder) to choose the exact plugins that are required for the specified toolbar items, no more or less. But it seems like I'm just supposed to somehow know what plugin is used for each toolbar item.

Is there really no way to create a build configuration based on the toolbar configuration? Alternatively, is there documentation somewhere listing every toolbar item in the configurator and what plugin(s) are required for it, so I can at least manually look at each toolbar item and match it with the plugins in the builder?

Answer (score 2):

The "easiest" way to find which CKEditor plugins provide which buttons will be looking for each name of the button in the "plugins" folder of CKEditor 4 together with `addButton`

For example, to figure out which plugin provides the 'JustifyLeft' button, search for something like
https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=addButton+justifyleft&type=

I know this is far from the ideal solution, but at least it should point you in the right direction.